# Counting files per owner

Tags: windows-7, script, ntfs, powershell

Using PowerShell how can I count the number of files that each owner has modified in the last 45 days?

This is how I am able to get counts by extension in the last 45 days:

```
gci -Recurse| where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)}| group Extension -NoElement
```

Instead of grouping by extension, I would like to group and count by owner. Thank you for your guidance!

Please note that this is counting through an entire directory structure

Answer (score 3):

```
gci -recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)} | % { get-acl $_ } | group Owner -NoElement
```

Will get you all the permissions, grouped by owner. Just remove the last pipe if you want them ungrouped.

i.e:

```
gci -recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)} | % { get-acl $_ }
```

Comment: thanks so much! now can i ask you, how can i run this script once for every directory in a parent directory. for example if i am in parent\, and parent dir has dir a, dir b, dir c, i want to run it once for each of those dirs?

Comment: and is there a way for it to not display details on every file, only the summary?

Comment: Setting `-recursive` on `gci` already runs it for all directories. If you only want to run it for one specific parent directory, just set the name of that dir. e.g: `gci nameOfDir -recurse |... ` If you want to see the count of how many items are owned by a specific owner, just use the first script (I assume that's what you mean by "Summary")